# Is Xiaomi Redmi 2 truly 64-bit ? Seller says so

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, xiaomi, redmi-2

My Phone was sold to me as 64-bit architecture, but the Apps like device control, show that it is actually 32-bit. What is correct?

And if anything is wrong,  how should I proceed?

Comment: What phone do you have? What firmware (version) is running on it and what apps are you running? Note that 32-bit applications work perfectly fine on 64-bit devices.

Comment: Phone is Redmi 2, Xiaomi. Yes,  everything works fine. Its just device control and device info apps show it as a 32-bit architecture.

Comment: Than it's just the firmware that is not 64-bit capable. The processor (Snapdragon 410) is 64-bit capable but without firmware support, it's just not working (like 32-bit Windows on a modern PC that would support 64-bit Windows).

Comment: What do you mean by firmware? Its default firmware which Shipped with the device.

Comment: It should be 64-bit, if its written on the box.

Comment: Sometimes (very rarely), manufacturers add 64-bit support to their firmware with an update (I'm pretty sure Xiaomi won't). 64-bit is just the processor. Check again with a more reputable app like [CPU-Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z) and post the *Kernel architecture* (it should be a 64-bit capable one).

Comment: I think,  device control is more reputable and Advanced than CPU Z. But, I have used both,  they show 32-bit architecture.

Comment: Then your OS is 32-bit. Nothing you can do about without installing a custom ROM. If you buy a 64-bit CPU you are not guaranteed a 64-bit OS. Many PCs a decade ago could handle 64-bit OS's but did come with 32-bit ones. It doesn't improve anything on your end, though. Unless you have more than 3.5 GB of RAM and need those 64-bit.

Comment: Bro, lets talk about phones not PC 

Comment: Where can I find a 64-bit OS.?

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com is my go-to website to find custom ROMs. Note that this usually comes with full wipes, loss of warranty and chance of bricking your device.

Comment: I have rooted it, and installed CM 12.1, lollipop . I can handle that stuff.

Comment: @GiantTree : can you summarize your comments into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redmi 2 has a *Chipset* that supports 64-bit but the *Bootloader* is not 64-bit ready.

Technically the seller didn't lie as the device is 64-bit architecture but you cannot install a 64-bit ROM (yet) since the bootloader is not 64-bit ready.

Related [MIUI thread 1](http://en.miui.com/thread-167385-1-1.html), [MIUI thread 2](http://54.243.194.135/thread-207253-1-1.html) and [Issue reported on GitHub](https://github.com/zwliew/android_device_xiaomi_hm2014811/issues/91)

There's a mention about Lollipop 64-bit version on [Chinese MIUI forum](http://www.miui.com/thread-3520171-1-1.html)

Comment: Isn't this false information ℹ from the seller side? This could be used against them.

Comment: @RahulParashar it's advertised of having a 64-bit capable CPU, this is not false advertising just because it's not used properly.

Comment: Bootloader is not 64-bit ready,  this is the false info. They advertise it as 64-bit.

Comment: Technically they're not lying as they're giving the info as 64-bit Chipset. If you see their official website, it says `Snapdragon 410 64-bit` and `64 bit computing`.

Comment: But, since you say Bootloader is not 64-bit ready, then How can you put a 64- bit OS on the device?